# EDITING ONE FOR ALL

Tags: python, django

how to make it so that if you change the value from true to false or vice versa in one place, all others change.
class Ralevant default is True
class Rooms default is True
class Registration value changes
and if in the registration class you change from true to false, then the Room class and Ralevant should also change

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import datetime

class Ralevant(models.Model):
    bool_roo = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.bool_roo}'
year=datetime.datetime.now().year
month=datetime.datetime.now().month
day = datetime.datetime.now().day

class Rooms(models.Model):
    room_num = models.IntegerField()
    room_bool = models.ForeignKey(Ralevant, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                  related_name='name1')  
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.room_num}'

class Registration(models.Model):
    rooms = models.ForeignKey(Rooms, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pasport_serial_num = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    img = models.FileField()
    visit_date = models.DateTimeField()
    leave_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(year=year,month=month,day=day+1,hour=12,minute=00,second=00))
    guest_count = models.IntegerField()
    room_bool = models.ForeignKey(Ralevant, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                  related_name='name2')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.rooms,self.last_name,self.first_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement it in your `views.py` or in your `serializers.py`, simple import model and update   `Model.objects.filter(pk=obj.pk).update()` something like that

Answer (score 0):

```
    def obj(request, pk,):
    reg = Registration.objects.get(pk=pk)
    room = Rooms.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if reg.room_bool == True:
        room.room_bool = True
        room.save()

    if reg.room_bool == False:
        room.room_bool = False
        room.save()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?